# How to solve a circular reference in decorators in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am currently implementing decorators for classes which contains metadata for its relation with other classes. In some cases however there are cyclic references, which although do not cause issues in the class themselves but do raise NameError's in the decorator containing the reference.

```
def foo(bar):
    def decorator_foo(func):
        return func
    return decorator_foo

@foo(bar=B)
class A:
    pass

@foo(bar=A)
class B:
    pass
```

The above example shows a simple way to raise the error. Is there a clean way to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are just simple functions, so in this case you can call them after you define the classes:

```py
def foo(bar):
    def decorator_foo(func):
        return func

    return decorator_foo


class A:
    pass


class B:
    pass


A = foo(bar=B)
B = foo(bar=A)
```